# How can I define a possible non existing relationships in jpa?

Tags: jpa, relationship

Let's say I have a table Item with a column named user_id and a Table User and another called Superuser:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Item(id int, user_id int, ..);  
CREATE TABLE User(id int, ..);  
CREATE TABLE Superuser(id int, ..);
```

Now, all Items have a User entry but only some have a Superuser entry, i.e. Item.user_id == User.id always and Item.user_id == Superuser.id is optional.

I can match the user part, but I have no clue how to map the Superuser one. For example, This doesn't work:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Superuser su;
    ...
```

This only allows user_id to be NULL, but I always have a user_id.
What I need is to tell jpa that "even though there will be a foreign key" there might not be a matching entry on the superuser table.

Comment: Let's start with the SQL database model... Can we assume that your `Item` table contains two foreign keys: `user_id int NOT NULL` (always) and `superuser_id int` (optional)?

Comment: @wypieprz No, as defined in the pseudo DDL there's only one foreign key in Item, an always matching primary key in User and an optional Entry in Superuser.

Comment: sounds more like the model should have a field of type "User" in Item class, and Superuser extends User, and that way if the object related is a User only then it gets the User, and if it is a Superuser then it gets the Superuser object.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it right, but you want to reference two tables (User and Superuser) with a single `user_id` column and a given Item should reference either User or Superuser table? If yes, you can achieve this with JPA's inheritance feature.

Comment: @NeilStockton Interesting, though USer and Superuser are not related, i.e. they don't share common fields. (fyi the relation already exists, I'm trying to model a legacy system)

Answer (score 4):

I managed to sort the most specific problem out, as I'm using hibernate as JPA backend.
Hibernate has a [NotFound](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2064) annotation precisely for this case:

> By default, when Hibernate cannot resolve the association because the expected associated element is not in database (wrong id on the association column), an exception is raised by Hibernate. This might be inconvenient for lecacy and badly maintained schemas. You can ask Hibernate to ignore such elements instead of raising an exception using the @NotFound annotation. This annotation can be used on a @OneToOne (with FK), @ManyToOne, @OneToMany or @ManyToMany association.

So the Hibernate solution looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Superuser su;
    ...
```

I'm still wondering if there's no other way accepted by the JPA Specification.